# can files on cloudflare disappear and what about performance

Tags: web, cloudflare

So i'm new in the web development world. But for some plugins i use at angular i notice that some use cloudflare.

like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">
```

So my question is should i download the files just in case or will they be permanent online ?

And will this improve the speed of my website if u use cloudflare or is it just the other way around. because i notice that some files are not using a compact css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that isn't actually referencing a site on CloudFlare, it is referencing a service called CDNJS, [CloudFlare provide CDN services for them](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cdnjs-the-fastest-javascript-repo-on-the-web/). These URLs are intended to the permanent endpoint in order to access scripts from [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com).

In ordinary CloudFlare sites, the CDN is transparent. CloudFlare works by proxying requests from the user to the origin server, they sit in the middle and perform caching and optimisation from [their 64 data centers around the world](https://blog.cloudflare.com/pho/), no need to alter your code at all.